# Value in properties file split by comma, reading file only loads first element

Tags: java, properties, split

I have a properties file called `configuration.properties`, within `configuration.properties` is the key-value pair:

```
email.recipients = sam@yahoo.com, bob@yahoo.com
```

In my `Util.java` class I load the `configuration.properties` file:

```
import org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException;

PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration("configuration.properties");
EMAIL_RECIPIENT_STRING = config.getString("email.recipients");
```

I expected to have `EMAIL_RECIPIENT_STRING` = "sam@yahoo.com, bob@yahoo.com", but I get `EMAIL_RECIPIENT_STRING` = "sam@yahoo.com" only. What's the reason for this happening?

Comment: Are you sure it is valid to include (unescaped) commas in a `Properties` file?  I don't know the finer details, but understand it is a specific format.

Comment: so what API is PropertiesConfiguration part of?

Comment: PropertiesConfiguration is part of Apache Commons. Woops, forgot to include that earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you're using Apache's [PropertiesConfiguration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/PropertiesConfiguration.html). The docs states

> value can contain value delimiters and will then be interpreted as a list of tokens. Default value delimiter is the comma ','.

`getString` only returns the first token. You need to use `getStringArray` to return all the properties

```
String recipients = config.getStringArray("email.recipients");
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually propConfig.setDelimiterParsingDisabled(true) is working, but you must load the config file after this setting, for example:

```
propConfig = new PropertiesConfiguration();
propConfig.setDelimiterParsingDisabled(true);
propConfig.load(propertiesFile);
```

if your code like is :

```
propConfig = new PropertiesConfiguration(propertiesFile); 
propConfig.setDelimiterParsingDisabled(true);
```

then the setting won't work

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are using [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration).
I'm also just guessing, but there is a getStringArray as well as a getString.  Based on your experience, maybe getString only returns the first value for a multi-value key.  Try getStringArray to get both values.